# Which form is correct?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, participles

Which form of these two sentences is correct?

> Mike finds your bag, but is disappointed that you have no apples left.
>
> Mike finds your bag, but gets disappointed that you have no apples left.

Comment: They are absolutely different forms. They are both correct.

Comment: They're both grammatically correct, but the second one sounds less fluent to me, because *to disappoint* is already a verb, so *he is disappointed* is a perfectly normal, valid use of the passive voice (he is disappointed* by the discovery that you have no apples left*).  Overuse of "get _____" seems to be a hallmark of ESL speakers; I would only use it with certain stock phrases (get sick, get well, get better, get angry, etc.) until you really have a feel for natural-sounding uses of it.